# Capture the current value of a dropdown in a calculated field

Tags: parameters, filtering, tableau-api

I am new to tableau but...

I have 4 worksheets on a dashboard with a drop-down filter that is linked to 3 of the 4 worksheets. The 3 linked worksheets work just fine, the fourth however needs to work a little differently.

The forth needs to show a calculated value `[Credit as Percent of Revenue]`. I would like the numerator `[Credit]` to be filtered according to the current value of the dropdown but the denominator `[Revenue]` to show total revenue regardless of the dropdown selection - both credit and revenue are in the same dataset - (that is why I believe I can't just simply link the sheet to the filter).

If I were programming in vb for instance i would use... "dropdown.Value" to get the current value selection and use that to filter the numerator.

I might be loosing the plot and barking up the wrong tree, if so please help!

Comment: Without a packaged workbook, it is very difficult to discern the layout, data structure and calculations, which (I think) in this case is necessary to provide an answer. Keep in mind that Parameters and filters are not the same but you can use parameter(s) in a filter. For example, let's say the user selects "Credit as %" as 5, you can filter sheet 4 by creating a calculated field that says "[credit as %] = [parameter]"; when the condition is met (When the Credit % is equal to the parameter value, the result is boolean TRUE. Then add this calculated field as a filter and only show TRUE.

Comment: Thanks Aron. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in the comments, but adding an an answer to get this post off the 'unanswered' list and for future reference.

Parameters and filters are not the same but you can use parameter(s) in a filter. For example, let's say the user selects the value "Credit as %" as 5 in a parameter, you can filter the sheet by creating a calculated field that says "[credit as %] = [parameter]"; when the condition is met (When the Credit % is equal to the parameter value, the result is boolean TRUE. Then add this calculated field as a filter and only show TRUE.